# How to filter results for prior to a specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2000

I have a query that grabs results from yesterday's date.  What i'd like to do is filter the results more by only returning results anything Pior to 6:30 AM or AFTER 7:15 AM.  If the results fall inbetween 6:30 and 7:15 AM I do not care about the result.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT Store_Id, DM_Corp_Received_Date
FROM   Register_Till_Count_Tb
WHERE  (Register_Transaction_Type = 'SOD') 
  AND  (Register_Till_Count_Datetime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
  AND  (Register_Till_Count_Datetime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

This is the output:

```
Store_ID DM_Corp_Received_Date
1        8/7/2012 5:29 AM
2        8/7/2012 6:15 AM
3        8/7/2012 6:29 AN
4        8/7/2012 5:53 AM
5        8/7/2012 6:12 AM
6        8/7/2012 6:23 AM
7        8/7/2012 6:00 AM
8        8/7/2012 6:08 AM
9        8/7/2012 5:39 AM
10       8/7/2012 6:14 AM
```

The Other tricky part is the above is in Central Time, My time zone is Eastern.  SO i need to convert it to Eastern THEN filter the results.

Comment: The where statement up above in my post is to grab YESTERDAYS date.  The "AND" most certainly works... I need to add another "AND" statement to search for TIME EARLIER then 6:30AM and LATER than 7:15...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following code. You might need to figure out how to pass in the correct value for 'now' to the query if you're running it on a schedule. For instance, does the Monday run look at Sunday, or does it look at Friday?

```
declare
  @dtNow         datetime ,
  @dtToday       datetime ,
  @dtFrom        datetime ,
  @dtThru        datetime ,
  @dtExcludeFrom datetime ,
  @dtExcludeThru datetime

set @dtNow         = getdate()
set @dtToday       = convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@dtNow,112),112)
set @dtFrom        = dateadd(day,-1,@dtToday) -- start-of-day yesterday
set @dtThru        = dateadd(ms,-3,@dtToday)  -- end-of-day yesterday (e.g., 2012-06-17 23:59:59.997)
set @dtExcludeFrom = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 06:30:00.000' , 120 )
set @dtExcludeThru = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 07:15:00.000' , 120 )

SELECT Store_Id ,
       DM_Corp_Received_Date
FROM Register_Till_Count_Tb
WHERE Register_Transaction_Type    =  'SOD'
  AND Register_Till_Count_Datetime     between @dtFrom        and @dtThru
  AND Register_Till_Count_Datetime not between @dtExcludeFrom and @dtExcludeThru
```

Here's a sample of the computed variable values:

```
@dtNow         2012-08-08 15:12:46.790
@dtToday       2012-08-08 00:00:00.000
@dtFrom        2012-08-07 00:00:00.000
@dtThru        2012-08-07 23:59:59.997
@dtExcludeFrom 2012-08-07 06:30:00.000
@dtExcludeThru 2012-08-07 07:15:00.000
```

With `datetime` values, the last 'tick' of the day might be `23:59:59.996` in SQL Server 2000. I can't remember, though (been too long since I had to deal with it). If it is, you'll need to change `dateadd(ms,-3,...)` to `dateadd(ms,-4,...)`.

As far as time zones go, SQL Server 2000 knows nothing about them. Knows nothing about UTC either. The date time value is just a count of days and fractional days since the epoch of 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000.

Whether it represents UTC or local time is entirely dependent on how your system is set up. If the date/time values come from users or other systems, you're dependent upon the data source for meaning.

As far as converting from Eastern Standard Time (EST) to Central Standard Time (CST) goes, CST is one hour earlier than Eastern time, so just subtract one hour to get EST: `dateadd(hour,-1,@my_datetime_value)` should it. If you've got to deal with the boundaries between daylight savings (summer) time and standard time, it get [much] more complex, since you need to know the source *locus* of the date/time value, and quite likely, whether or not the recording system normalized the date/time value in any way.

For instance, prior to 2005, the State of Indiana was ostensibly in the Central Time Zone. However, the selection of time zone — Central (UTC-6) or Eastern (UTC-7) — and whether or not daylight savings time was observed was made on a county-by-county basis. Some counties liked Easter Time. Though some counties did observer daylight savings time, most did not. This effectively made those counties toggle between Central Time and Eastern time depending on what time of the year it was.

In 2006, Indiana passed a law and [sort of] standardized on the Eastern time zone and the observation of daylight savings time...except that 18 of Indiana's 92 counties are on Central Time (7 in the northwest corner of the state, because they are near Chicago, which is Central Time, and 11 in the southwest corner of the state, just to be ornery since they're near nothing). And then on 11 March 2007, Pulaski county changed from Central Time to Easter Time. No idea what Indiana has done since them.

For more — much more — on the difficulties on dealing with this sort of stuff, See the [excellent!] book [*Calendrical Calculations*](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1164334/?site_locale=en_GB) by [Nachum Dershowitz](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/nachumd/Homepage.html) and [Edward M. Reingold](http://emr.cs.uiuc.edu/~reingold/). The book has its own web site:

http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/calendar-book/index.shtml

[image: Calendrical Calculations Cover]

If I was going to approach that problem, I would design some sort of mapping table or tables to let me look up the appropriate adjustment to be made given a date/time value and a locus like a zip code or a base zip code. The first 3 digits of a US zip code give you the base zip code for a city or region. For instance, the base zip for Seattle is 98100.

Finding the data to load in the tables regarding time zone usage over time, whether or not daylight savings time was observed in that location and if so, what the switch-over dates were for a particular year or range of years in each location is likely to be something of a challenge.

Comment: @Shmewnix: Eh? It's been years since I had to deal with SQL Server 2000, but I don't believe I'm doing anything WRT to T-SQL that SQL Server 2000 didn't know about. Edited to add the two missing variable declarations, though.

Comment: This works great!  I am a little foggy on what to do with the time conversion... My initial thought is to First convert the DM_Corp_Receive_Date colum to eastern time (I need to add an hour)  can I do something like this in the query: SELECT Store_Id ,        DM_Corp_Received_Date as (dateadd(hour,+1,@My_date_time)) Obviously this does not work... I'm a little confused on how to add the hours. I need to display the actual time opened (eastern time not central).

Comment: I figured this out.  I just add the hour in VB.net for the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BETWEEN function. For example

```
SELECT value
FROM table
WHERE date_col NOT BETWEEN '2012-08-08 06:30' AND '2012-08-08 07:15'
```

To convert the time to eastern, you can either alter your filter (add an hour) or you can use

```
DATEADD(hh,-1,date_col)
```

Which will basically subtract an hour from each date.  Obviously it will be quicker to change 1 date than to change all the dates in a table, so just changing the filter dates will be more efficient.

If you have more questions, maybe you can post more info.

Comment: The problem is I'm running the query for Yesterdays date.  (This will be in a program that is running by windows scheduler) so I will always need "Yesterdays" date.